# After add a new WFE server, cannot login sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, server-farm

Original we only have one all-in-one server. Recently we add a new server (VM) and decide to use it as WFE. The old one will become APP server. I followed the procedure here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752(v=office.15).aspx#addserver

Basically I install sharepoint on the new server and run product configuration wizard. I verified with a client computer I can login to sharepoint site (with URL point to original server). Then I updated the HOST file to have the URL point to new WFE server.

When I browse to the URL I get password prompt as usual. After login 3 times it throw me a blank white page. I have verified the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application is started on WFE.

However I can login to central administration page at the WFE server localhost using URL like http: appserver:30895/

What else I have missed? Thanks.

Comment: did you update your AAM?

Comment: No. Because I only use the URL as default zone. I have 2 web application plus the central admin page: http://appserver:30895, http://web.domain.com (default zone), http://blog.domain.com (default zone)

Comment: After more test, I believe it is authentication issue. By some reason it doesn't authenticate with AD at all.

Comment: do you have the kerberos Authentication?

Comment: I checked on manage web application I am using CLAIMS for the 2 web app and Windows for central admin as auth provider.
I just tested point the URL back to old server I can login again. So I don't know why new server do not do authentication properly.

Comment: can you browse the site with your Server name and port number...i.e http://webserver:port....Couple of things to check...if kerberos being used then SPN issue, Make sure the Object Cache Configured properly, Make Sure App Pool Account on the Web server having proper permission on server.

Comment: I will test it out tonight when I back to the test box. I was testing using the vm HOST machine's IE. The HOST did not join the domain. I can login using this method when I only have one server VM.

Comment: also try to access the site from the web server...from IIS manager>right click on the web Site > then browse it....see what happened.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13579/discussion-between-mark-and-waqas-sarwar-mcse)

Comment: I have disconnected the WFE and connect again still the same. I just found that "Claims to Windows Token Service" is stopped (I think it is default?). Will it cause problem? I will create a new win2008 instance and join farm again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning, I have a single VM have SQL, Sharepoint 2013, AD, etc installed. Everything is running fine.

Later, I clone this VM, change this computername (or hostname) and join it to orginial server's farm. I can complete the installation wizard and product configuration wizard. However, as I mentioned in the question, users cannot login using this new server as WFE.

I think the cause is the VM is not clear. It has numberous settings including the AD stuff on server.

So I create a new VM with a blank new install win2008. Install everything and join to the existing farm. Everything is fine this time.

Thanks for all of your input!

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the system as a "Stand Alone" install (see dialog box in figure 1 of [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) I believe you are not able to add any additional servers to the farm. If this was done, you'll most likely have to completely re-install the farm on your new host, migrate the content databases, then reinstall your original server to join the farm.

Comment: No I am not using standalone. In the old server I have SQL2008, ADDS there.